# Traits with stricter associated type bounds than supertrait

Tags: rust

I have a simple trait with an associated type with no bounds.

```
trait Board {
    type Move;
    fn moves(&self) -> Vec<Self::Move>;
}
```

I also want to use this trait as a supertrait. In particular, I want my new subtrait to have stricter bounds on the associated type. Something like this:

```
trait TextBoard: Board {
    type Move: fmt::Debug; // Trying to tighten bounds on associated type
    fn printMoves(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.moves());
    }
}
```

The example is highly simplified, but seems to show the problem: The compiler thinks I'm trying to create a new associated type, but I just want the subtrait to require tighter bounds. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Would creating a free-standing function `printMoves` which takes a `&Board<Move = T>` where `T: fmt::Debug` solve your issue, or are you bend on a refinement trait?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's what you asked for:

```
trait TextBoard: Board
where
    Self::Move: Debug,
{
    // ...
}
```

All the bounds on  a trait have to be in the "headline"; you can't impose additional restrictions once you start writing the body of the trait. This bound will prevent you from writing `impl TextBoard for Foo` when `<Foo as Board>::Move` does not implement `Debug` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3d7067d4429ee3ea7d28f0af9dd1adf8&version=stable)).

---

Maybe that is what you want, but do you really need to *prevent* implementing `TextBoard` for other types? For some type there could be another way to write `print_moves` that makes more sense, and the `Debug` requirement is just noise. In that case you probably want to skip the `where` clause and move the body of `print_moves` to a *blanket `impl`*:

```
trait TextBoard {
    fn print_moves(&self);
}

impl<B: Board> TextBoard for B
where
    B::Move: Debug, // or <Self as Board>::Move: Debug
{
    fn print_moves(&self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.moves());
    }
}
```

With this version, you still don't need to write an `impl` for types where `Self::Move: Debug`, but you're not *prevented* from writing an `impl` for other types where that doesn't hold. It's more of an *extension* than a *refinement*.

---

On the other hand, you should pretty much always implement `Debug` for every type, so is it really useful to have that trait? Maybe what you want is just an optional method on `Board` that's implemented when `Move: Debug`:

```
trait Board {
    type Move;

    fn moves(&self) -> Vec<Self::Move>;

    fn print_moves(&self)
    where
        Self::Move: Debug,
    {
        println!("{:?}", self.moves());
    }
}
```

This is like the original version, but doesn't require the addition of a new `TextBoard` trait, so it will probably cut down on the number of explicit bounds you have to write. Many of the standard library traits such as [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) have optional methods defined with bounds like this. The downside, besides the requirement that `Move` *must* be `Debug`, is that it clutters the `Board` trait with printing code, which you might not consider really part of what it means to be a `Board`.